# Why the private property of another string can be referenced directly in the implementation of java String constructor

Tags: java, string, constructor, private

I have reviewed `Java.lang.String` implementation.The constructor make me confused.
why `result.value,result.count,result.offset` can be used directly.
As the property of the three are just **private**!!!

```
 /** The value is used for character storage. */
private final char value[];

/** The offset is the first index of the storage that is used. */
private final int offset;

/** The count is the number of characters in the String. */
private final int count;

public String(StringBuilder builder) {
    String result = builder.toString();
    this.value = result.value;
    this.count = result.count;
    this.offset = result.offset;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Java method can access the private field values of *any* instance of the class that declares it.  It is part of the language.

(Maybe you are thinking that "private" means the same thing in Java as it does in real life.  It doesn't.  The Java access modifiers are not primarily a mechanism for maintaining data privacy or security.  What the access modifiers are *primarily* about is maintaining abstraction boundaries; i.e. preventing one class from depending on the internal implementation details of another class.)

Answer (score 1):

`result.value,result.count,result.offset` come from the parameter `builder`

Answer (score 0):

**Private Access Modifier**

Methods, Variables and Constructors that are declared private can only be accessed within the declared class itself i.e by all its members.
Private access modifier is the most restrictive access level. Class and interfaces cannot be private.
Variables that are declared private can be accessed outside the class if public methods are present in the class which can retrieve the private entity of that class.